# What feasibility studies are being conducted by ISRO concerning manned flight?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, isro, research

I was reading [this article](http://www.spacenews.com/article/isros-future-plans-will-focus-low-cost-exploration) (sorry for the terrible formatting), and I noticed this statement made by an ISRO official:

> Nair said no decision has yet been made about sending Indian astronauts into space. "**We are assessing the feasibility of manned missions and these studies will take another year to complete,**" he said. "Once approved by the government, it will take seven to eight years for ISRO to put an Indian in orbit."

The part about feasibility studies caught my eye - hasn't it kind of already been proven feasible to put people in space? It's been done countless times before. What is feasibility studies is ISRO conducting?

Comment: I would venture studies is actually about ISRO, it's indigenous technology, training & stuff - rather than whether manned space-flight itself is feasible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Everyone said it's not regarding feasibility but it's matter of budget and absence of human rated space vehicle and components

#### Budget

> Development of a fully autonomous
> orbital vehicle to carry a two-
> member crew into a low-Earth orbit
> (LEO) has already begun. ISRO
> sources said the flight is likely to be
> in 2016. Government had allocated
> 950 million (US \$14.5 million) for pre-
> project initiatives for 2007 through
> 2008. A manned mission into space
> would require about 124 billion (US
> \$1.9 billion) and a period of seven
> years. Planning Commission estimates
> that a budget of 50 billion (US
> \$765.0 million) is required for initial
> work on the manned mission during
> the eleventh five-year plan (2007–
> 12). A project report prepared by
> ISRO has been cleared by space
> commission. In February 2009
> the Government of India gave the
> green light for the manned space
> flight programme, due to [launch](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_human_spaceflight_programme) in
> 2016.

#### Human rated vehicle

The failure of GSLV  in 2010 one made in India and other imported from Russia made the human space program to loss it's momentum.

> The NASA CCP human-rating
> standards require that the
> probability of loss on ascent is no
> more than 1 in 500, and that the
> probability of loss on descent is no
> more than 1 in 500. The overall
> mission loss risk, which includes
> vehicle risk from micrometeorites
> and orbital debris while in orbit for
> up to 210 days is no more than 1 in
> 270. [2] Maximum sustained G-loads
> are limited to three Earth-[standard](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human-rating_certification)
> g's

ISRO must ensure that these conditions are satisfied

#### Space accessories

ISRO has planned to make everything indigenouly instead of buying from overseas countries. So lots of research must done to ensure [reliability](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2012-09-17/news/33902713_1_cryogenic-engine-gslv-mk-iii-radhakrishnan-today)

> Radhakrishnan, however, said ISRO
> already has a budget of Rs 150 crore
> for conducting pre-project studies and
> developing critical technologies including
> environmental control, space suit,
> reentry and crew escape system. The
> rocket must have man-rating, he
> noted.

And another important thing I think is training astronauts and ISRO is now building astronaut training facilities in Bangalore and still it's under construction and it will become functional by [2013](http://www.siliconindia.com/shownews/_ISRO_to_set_up_astronaut_training_institute-nid-48055-cid-2.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to ISRO, the maiden flight of the GSLV-Mark-III, with mission designation of LVM3-X1, is scheduled for April 2014, and will be carrying the Indian crew capsule. This will be a suborbital test flight, and will test the aerothermal characteristics of the capsule during atmospheric re-entry, and likely also communication blackout.